# How to pass value to another tab without starting Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

I have 2 Tabs - Tab1 and Tab2, Tab1Activity and Tab2Activity.
I want to pass values from Tab1Actvity to Tab2Activity but dont want to start Tab2Activity.
When i try below code it gives null value:

**In Tab1Activity**

```
getParent().getIntent().putExtra("key", "value");
```

**In Tab2Activity**

```
String valueString=getParent().getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
System.out.println("Testing.....: "+valueString);
```

Comment: Why don't you use static fields and getters and setters

Comment: @sandy becouse it's wrong ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really discourage you from using global variables by extending the Application class. If your application goes to the background, (e.g. due a phone call) the android system might decide to kill your application. When the call is finished your application and the activity stack will be restored, but your activity state will be lost.

I'd rather suggest you to use broadcasts to send data to another activity.

In your Tab1Activity:

```
Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
dataIntent.setAction("com.your.app.DATA_BROADCAST");
dataIntent.putExtra("tag", "your data");
sendBroadcast(dataIntent);
```

Tab2Activity:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {    
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {    
    String yourData = intent.getStringExtra("tag");
  }
};

IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("com.your.app.DATA_BROADCAST");
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You definitely want to reconsider using Activities as the content of your tabs. The more standard approach is to use one Activity that uses Tabs to only show part of the layout when a particular tab is selected.

The Android documentation has an excellent worked example, check out [Hello, TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Alternative

If for some reason you do need to use Activities, you can pass information between them by either adding values to the extras bundle within the Intent your using to open each Activity, or by extending the [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class.

By extending the Application class (and implementing it as a Singleton) you get an object that will exist whenever any of your application components exist, providing a centralized place to store and transfer complex object data between application components.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use static classes or SharedPreferences for data transfer between tabs.
the correct way is setting a static field into the activity that creates the tabs

```
public class greformanews extends TabActivity {

       public static String JorgesysTitle;
...
...
...
```

so in your Activity defined in tab 1

```
@Override
 protected void onPause() { 
    greformanews.JorgesysTitle = "JORGESYS =)";
 super.onPause();
}
```

in your Activity defined in tab 2

```
//get  value defined in Activity 1 !:)
String Title =  greformanews.JorgesysTitle
```